# Can any one suggest any encryption decryption algorithm which interop between c and c#

Tags: c#, c

Can any one suggest any encryption algorithm which interop between c and c# means encrypt in c language and decrypt in c# & vice versa

Comment: i have used Rijndael algo but in c# it requires salt but in c it doesn,t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like AES available under System.Security.Cryptography.

You can find an example of using it under C# here - [Using AES encryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp)

When deriving IV and SALT you might find this utility class useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx

I cannot directly answer the C/C++ side, however trawling SO posts there's plenty of answers such as: [encrypt- decrypt with AES using C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489379/encrypt-decrypt-with-aes-using-c-c)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx its a managed code and framework dependent.I want pure c or c++code. or tell me the way to use managed code without framework dependency

Comment: This is the C# side only, I've given links to the native side, never done much that side myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
i have used Rijndael algo but in c# it requires salt but in c it doesn,t
```

You can simply re-write the C  code in C# as basic operators will not change.

Use `pinvoke` wherever neccessary.

**REFERENCE**: `.Zero , Charles Petzold. chapter 7`

Google the book name to get the download link