# encrypt a text message along with binary data

Tags: c++, encryption, binary

Can I put text string (serving as password) and binary data (an image file actually) together and encrypt them and then save into new a file. To view the image, first, check if password matches, if yes, read the binary data and save as image. I have to use C++.

Very new to C++. Is that technically possible? Can someone give me some ideas how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be actually secure, use somebody else's implementation of an encryption algorithm. What you're looking for is a symmetric key encryption algorithm, such as AES. You'd use the password to encrypt the image, *not* save the password, and then the password would decrypt said image.

And, as luck would have it, [somebody else asked about using AES to encrypt and decrypt things in C and C++ here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489379/encrypt-decrypt-with-aes-using-c-c)